# How to run matplotlib FuncAnimation using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, jupyter

It takes a long time (20 secs) to render 500 frames of this matplotlib animation using the code below.

Is it possible to produce the same animation `anim` but make use of more CPU cores, such as with the use of `multiprocessing` to create more processes that runs `FuncAnimation` for different ranges of frames, then combine all the frames together at the end into `anim`?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams["animation.html"] = "jshtml"
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 100
plt.ioff()

def animate(frame_num):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x + 2*np.pi * frame_num/100)
    line.set_data((x, y))
    return line

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([])
ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, frames=100,
)
```